# Not sure where to implements parcelable ArrayList after click item in RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, arraylist, parcelable

I wanna pass some of informations of the selected item to be viewed in new activity AboutApp.kt, but here I test by one info only (name). I do not have any trouble with RecyclerView, it works. I've seen many ways to do parcelable ArrayList object but feeling confuse where activity to be implemented, so it's getting error in MainActivity and AboutApp (destination intent).

A piece code **MainActivity.kt** getting error in showSelectedHerbal, when I use **position** to putExtra

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var rvHerbal: RecyclerView
    private var list: ArrayList<Herbal> = arrayListOf()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        rvHerbal = findViewById(R.id.rv_herbal)
        rvHerbal.setHasFixedSize(true)

        list.addAll(HerbalData.listData)
        showRecyclerList()
    }

    private fun showRecyclerList() {
        rvHerbal.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        val listHerbalAdapter = ListHerbalAdapter(list)
        rvHerbal.adapter = listHerbalAdapter

        listHerbalAdapter.setOnItemClickCallback(object : ListHerbalAdapter.OnItemClickCallback {
            override fun onItemClicked(data: Herbal) {
                showSelectedHerbal(data)
            }
        })
    }

    ........

    private fun showSelectedHerbal(data: Herbal) {
        val moveIntent = Intent(this, AboutApp::class.java)
        moveIntent.putExtra("Example_Item", list!![position])
        this.startActivity(moveIntent)
    }

    .......
}
```

A piece code from **AboutApp.kt** that getting error in herbalName(). I know that I haven't implemented the parcelable so it's wrong

```
        val intent = intent
        val herbalData: HerbalData = intent.getParcelableExtra("Example_Item")

        val title: String = herbalData.herbalName()

        val itemName = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.item_name)
        itemName.text = title
```

I'm so sorry, I attach you some of activities that I confuse may be one of them is the right place to be implement parcelable. Here is my data class **Herbal.kt**

```
data class Herbal(
    var name: String = "",
    var detail: String = "",
    var photo: Int = 0
)
```

A piece code of the object **HerbalData.kt**

```
object HerbalData {
    private val herbalName = arrayOf("Cengkeh",
        "Ginseng",
        "Jahe")

    ..........

    val listData: ArrayList<Herbal>
        get() {
            val list = arrayListOf<Herbal>()
            for (position in herbalName.indices) {
                val herbal = Herbal()
                herbal.name = herbalName[position]
                herbal.detail = herbalDetail[position]
                herbal.photo = herbalImage[position]
                list.add(herbal)
            }
            return list
        }
}
```

Help me please where activity to be write the parcelable ArrayList and how to fix it. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Ok I will edit it

Comment: You have `private val herbalName` herbalName private, so you can't access it in AboutApp.kt, + you can make it parcelable via @Parcelize annotation

Comment: I have removed the Private but now I have a noticed like this Expression 'herbalName' of type 'Array<String>' cannot be invoked as a function. The function 'invoke()' is not found. What's wrong? Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the error in your AboutApp.kt is because you have `herbalName` private in your HerbalData object. Remove the private modifier to access it there.

Just add @Parcelize annotation over your data class to automatically generate `writeToParcel` and `createFromParcel` methods for you!

```kotlin
@Parcelize
data class Herbal(...) : Parcelable
```

Add this in your build.gradle file:

```
androidExtensions {
    features = ["parcelize"]
}
```

**PS:** Reference: https://medium.com/@BladeCoder/a-study-of-the-parcelize-feature-from-kotlin-android-extensions-59a5adcd5909

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have removed the Private but now I have a noticed like this Expression 'herbalName' of type 'Array<String>' cannot be invoked as a function. The function 'invoke()' is not found. What's wrong? Can you help me, please?

Comment: @MeyLin herbalName is array of multiple strings as you defined `arrayOf("Cengkeh", "Ginseng", "Jahe")`, you can take an element using `herbalName[0]` or 1 or 2 putting inside square brackets. or you can iterate over that using for loop.

Comment: Sorry about this. The reason I couldn't use number inside the bracket, the herbalName will be shown is based on selected item from listview so it must be a random and I have 10 data in real code, not only 3. I've told u that I use Recyclerview in my question, I've tested it and it works to show the list. My trouble comes when I will show the detail of the selected item and use the herbalName only as the sample. Do you have any idea about the herbalName? Thanks before for your help.

Comment: @MeyLin btw before answering that, can i ask why are you using `intent` to get the HerbalData? it is singleton (object) you can access it easily

Comment: @MeyLin you can access the position from the recyclerview, you're probably implementing `onBindViewHolder(holder: MyHolder, position: Int)` you are given position, whichever item is selected by user you can use that.

Comment: I'm not sure about this. I'm the new one in android. I've seen a tutorial on Youtube to solve this parcelable problem and I follow it, but I do not understand. That's why I couldn't implement it with my project.

Comment: onBindViewHolder, I've made it before and it's same like your suggestion. The error now, just in destination activity (AboutApp.kt). I'm so sorry, too much asked @AnimeshSahu

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212486/discussion-between-animesh-sahu-and-mey-lin).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you read [this](https://medium.com/the-lazy-coders-journal/easy-parcelable-in-kotlin-the-lazy-coders-way-9683122f4c00).

You just have to make the `Herbal` class `Parcelable`.

```
data class Herbal(
    var name: String = "",
    var detail: String = "",
    var photo: Int = 0
) : Parcelable {

    companion object {
        @JvmField
        val CREATOR = object : Parcelable.Creator<Herbal> {
            override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel) = Herbal(parcel)
            override fun newArray(size: Int) = arrayOfNulls<Herbal>(size)
        }
    }

    private constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this(
        name = parcel.readString(),
        detail = parcel.readString(),
        photo = parcel.readInt(),
    )

    override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
        parcel.writeString(name)
        parcel.writeString(detail)
        parcel.writeInt(photo)
    }

    override fun describeContents() = 0
}
```

Comment: I really apreciate your answer, I wanna say thanks. But I also have an error in destination activity (AboutApp.kt) and another person here tell me to fix it. I'm so sorry not voted you. May God bless u always.